# Можно ли использовать в JAVA аннотациях переменные?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Подскажите можно ли как то прописать в аннотации переменную? Использую Spring boot.

Нужно реализовать чтобы название таблицы бралось из application.properties файла. Что то подобное возможно?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Const.tableName)
@Getter
@Setter
public class UnreliableTaxpayer {       

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "IIN")
    private String iin;
    @Column(name = "NNP")
    private Integer nnp;

}

@Getter
public class Const {

    @Value("${table.name}")
    public static String tableName;
}
```

И само значение берется из application.properties

```
table.name=z_026_unreliable_taxpayer_tmp
```

Comment: В таких случаях проще и правильнее - воспользоваться xml-конфигурацией, а не аннотациями.

Comment: А с аннотациями такое возможно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько мне известно, на аннотациях такое можно реализовать только костылём. Например, определить свою аннотацию и переопределить [PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.html) так, чтобы он эту аннотацию обрабатывал:

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.example.PropertyNamingStrategy
table.name=name_from_config
```

**TableName.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TableName {
    public String value();
}
```

**SomeEntity.java**

```
package com.example.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.example.TableName;

@Entity
@TableName("table.name")
public class SomeEntity {
    ...
}
```

**PropertyNamingStrategy.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class PropertyNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier id, JdbcEnvironment ctx) {
        String propertyName = null;
        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("com.example.domain." + id.getText());
            if (cls.isAnnotationPresent(TableName.class)) {
                TableName annotation = (TableName) cls.getAnnotation(TableName.class);
                propertyName = annotation.value();
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {}

        // В этом месте не стоит рассчитывать на возможность
        // использовать @Value или внедрить Environment, так как
        // Spring Boot создаёт EntityManagerFactory раньше.
        String tableName = null;
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream is = Application.class
                            .getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
            properties.load(is);
            tableName = properties.getProperty(propertyName);
        }
        catch (IOException exc) {}

        return new Identifier(tableName, false);
    }
}
```

**Внимание!** Вышеприведённая реализация чрезвычайно наивна, в ней нет никаких проверок, в ней есть хардкод и компоновка кода дурацкая, для понятности. Не использовать как есть.

Кроме того, использование `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` привяжет приложение к Hibernate.

Как я уже писал, проще и лучше перенести маппинг в xml-конфигурацию.

**P.S.** Может быть, такое можно сделать на java-конфигурации, но я ей не пользуюсь.